# How to solve "Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?" when using pdf2image?

Tags: python, pdf, pdf2image

I am using module pdf2drive to convert my pdf file to image. But when I run, an error message poped up:
"Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?"

I installed the poppler and I've added the path to Environment variables. In command prompt, it can run normally.
[message in command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZL2G.png)

But afterwards, the same error message reported in IDE.
[error message in IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjXfQ.png)

What should I do to solve this problem? Thanks!

This is my code:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
import sys
from pdf2image import convert_from_path
import os

pdf_file = 'historical_data.pdf'
pages = convert_from_path(pdf_file,600)
image_path = 'pdf_image/'
image_counter = 1

for page in pages:

    filename = "page_"+str(image_counter)+".png"
    page.save(image_path+filename,600)
    image_counter +=1
```

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code or error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Is the updated `PATH` available in your IDE? Did you restart it after configuring the system `PATH`?

Comment: Sorry about posting image, I will not do it next time. I installed the latest version and it can recognize by IDE. But there is a new problem: "I/O Error: Couldn't open file 'historical_data.pdf': No error."  I am not sure is this because this file is not ASCII-encoded